# SQL Query to find missing rows between two related tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables:

### Table A

- ID
- ABC_ID
- VAL

### Table B

- ID
- ABC_ID
- VAL

These two tables are directly related to each other through the `ABC_ID` column.

I want to find all the `VAL` column values in table A which are *not* present in table B for the same ABC_ID.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
SELECT A.ABC_ID, A.VAL FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.ABC_ID = A.ABC_ID AND B.VAL = A.VAL)
```

or

```
SELECT A.ABC_ID, A.VAL FROM A WHERE VAL NOT IN 
    (SELECT VAL FROM B WHERE B.ABC_ID = A.ABC_ID)
```

or

```
SELECT A.ABC_ID, A.VAL LEFT OUTER JOIN B 
    ON A.ABC_ID = B.ABC_ID AND A.VAL = B.VAL FROM A WHERE B.VAL IS NULL
```

Please note that these queries do not require that ABC_ID be in table B at all.  I think that does what you want.

Comment: The join will have the side effect of multipliyng records if the TableB has more than one record with matching ABC_ID and VAL

Comment: Related: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/

Comment: This does not work as Inner query returns you VAL for a different ABC_ID as well.  E.g. Table B has values 1, 123, 1; 2, 123, 2, 3, 134, 5 and Table A has values 1, 123, 1; 2,123, 5;  Ideally I want to get the Table A 2, 123, 5 to be returned

Comment: Remus, the JOIN filters out the matching rows, so only table A rows that are not matched in table B will contribute to the result set.  Because the rows that will show up are contributed solely from the table A side of the JOIN (through the LEFT OUTER), I think each row will show up once only.

Comment: In first solution, you should use 1 (or any other letter) instead of (*) to optimize query.

Comment: @alphaprolix: I don't know where this idea got started, but you do not need to avoid the * in this circumstance.  It's obvious to the query optimizer that you're checking for the existence of rows, not returning data, and no use will be made of the column list.

Comment: @LarryLustig: using select 1 [does have](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/select-vs-select-1-with) a performance benifit, but the difference is so little that people usually ignore it.

Comment: If that (extremely minimal) parsing difference still exists in SQL Server, I would consider it a flaw of their parser.  As Celko states in a comment to the article you cited, most modern engines will perform identically.

Comment: I see a ~25% speed-up with `select 1`. The 2nd query is about 6x as slow as the 1st query. (The 3rd query doesn't seem to be valid SQLite syntax.). My test case: A and B both contain ~600k records, and the mapping is 1:1

Comment: (edited) Modified version of solution option #3 above.  I couldn't get the original to work.  This version works for me:


"SELECT A.ABC_ID, A.VAL FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B 
    ON A.ABC_ID = B.ABC_ID AND A.VAL = B.VAL WHERE B.VAL IS NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).
Join combines content from table A and table B using a link, the `ON` part of the request.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    A
INNER JOIN
    B
ON
    B.ABC_ID = A.ABC_ID
WHERE
    B.VAL <> A.VAL
```

Basically we are combining table A with table B on ABC_ID and then checking where A.VAL is not equal to B.VAL. The joined data with `INNER JOIN` only contains records where both table A and B have ABC_ID present ().

Answer (score -3):

DECLARE @start_date DATETIME= '04-01-2021';
DECLARE @End_date DATETIME= '04-30-2021';
declare @min int
declare @max int
select @min  =min(test_uid),
@max  =max(test_uid)
from test
where   DATE >= @START_DATE
AND   DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @END_DATE)

select test_UID+1 as FirstMissingId, nextid - 1 as LastMissingId  into #tmp from (select test.*,lead(test_UID) over (order by test_UID) as nextid  from test
where  test_UID between @min and   @max ) test where nextid <> test_UID+1
CREATE TABLE  #tmp1 (  ID INT   )
go
declare @lastmissingid  BIGINT
, @firstmissingid BIGINT
declare recscan cursor for
select   firstmissingid ,lastmissingid from #tmp
open recscan
fetch next from recscan into   @firstmissingid ,@lastmissingid
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
declare @maxcnt int = @lastmissingid
declare @mincnt, int =@firstmissingid

WHILE @Counter <= @maxcnt
BEGIN  INSERT #tmp1 values(@Counter)
SET @Counter +=  1
END
fetch next from recscan into @firstmissingid ,@lastmissingid
end
close recscan
deallocate recscan

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.  Please also view the [help page on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to see how you can format your code.

Comment: Seems to be irrelevant to the question asked. Maybe you posted this as answer to some other question.  Also, no explanations have been provided.