# How do you compare records within the multiple tables but look for different or missing values

Tags: sql

Here is a version of my Table:

```
p.productid | pp.productid|  pp.productpricingid | p.erpsku | pp.countrycode | pp.productstatus
 1            1                    1             AAAAA        US             Active
 2            2                    2             BBBBB        US             Active
 3            3                    3             CCCCC        US             Active
 4            4                    4             DDDDD        US             Active

 1            1                    5             AAAAA        CA             Active
 2            2                    6             BBBBB        CA             Active
 3            3                    7             CCCCC        CA             InActive
```

So I have 2 tables products, and product pricing. I need help writing a query that will pull all the values that are Active in US but inactive or nonexistant in CA. So for the example above the valeus CCCCC and DDDDD should be pulled.  The tricky thing is that all this data lives in both the product and productpricing tables, which I combine to make one data set. Then within that dataset I have to write another nested query where I find all the differences. Right now I can find all the values that are not in the US table, but Im not sure if this query is accurate.

Here is a sample of my Query:

```
select p.erpsku from

product p, productpricing pp

where

p.productid = pp.productid

and pp.countrycode = 'us'

and pp.productstatus = 'Active'

and p.productid not in (select p.productid from product p, productpricing pp where p.productid = pp. productid and 

pp.countrycode = 'CA' )
```

However I am unsure if this query is accurate at all. I would appreciate any help I could get with this.

Comment: In your CA sub-select you'll want to make sure you're only looking for  statuses where it's "Active", if you can have records where the countrycode is 'CA' and the productstatus is 'InActive'.

Comment: Google [sql join find missing records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826929/sql-query-to-find-missing-rows-between-two-related-tables)

Comment: Hi Danny, I changed the status in the subselect to inactive, however the returning values are of all skus that are present in the US list but not present in the CA list. I need to find the values where the skus are present and active in the us list but present and INACTIVE in the CA list. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user3512974 - yes, but you *want* the sub-select to check for `'Active'` because you're checking where p.productd NOT IN the sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

If you include Danny's suggestion you've got it right.  Perhaps if you structure your query as a `CTE` the solution will become more obvious to you?

```
create table #DataTable (
     erpsku varchar(20)
    ,countrycode char(2)
    ,productstatus varchar(8)
);


insert #DataTable
values
     ('AAAAA', 'US', 'Active')
    ,('BBBBB', 'US', 'Active')
    ,('CCCCC', 'US', 'Active')
    ,('DDDDD', 'US', 'Active');

-- All regions' data in one table
insert #DataTable
values
     ('AAAAA', 'CA', 'Active')
    ,('BBBBB', 'CA', 'Active')
    ,('CCCCC', 'CA', 'InActive');


;with US_Active as
(
    select
        erpsku
    from #DataTable
    where countrycode = 'US'
    and productstatus = 'Active'
)
, CA_Active as
(
    select
        erpsku
    from #DataTable
    where countrycode = 'CA'
    and productstatus = 'Active'
)
, US_Not_CA as
(
    select
        erpsku
    from US_Active
    EXCEPT
    select
        erpsku
    from CA_Active
)
select * from US_Not_CA;
```

I've abbreviated your sample table for simplicity.  What I've done with erpsku could be done just as well with ProdustID.