# Using SQL Server 2016 SPLIT_STRING

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I'm using

```
SELECT PMID, PMCID
FROM Publications 
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT('29535196,29533737,29425496,28495678,26688618' ,',') ON value = Publications.PMID
```

And that works great to pull the publications that I have in the `Publications` table, but is there a way to restructure the query to show what values are missing? Meaning if 29533737 is not in the database then my result would be 29533737. In the past if you were check to see if two tables had all records it would be like [SQL Query to find missing rows between two related tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826929/sql-query-to-find-missing-rows-between-two-related-tables)

How can I do it with a comma separated string? Do I have to make a temp table and then process for the missing row?

Thanks

Tested code:

```
SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT('1234567, 29535196,29533737,29425496,28495678,26688618' ,',') AS v 
LEFT JOIN Publications p ON v.value = p.PMID
WHERE p.PMID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT value, PMID, PMCID
FROM   Publications 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN STRING_SPLIT('29535196,29533737,29425496,28495678,26688618' ,',')
  ON value = Publications.PMID
 -- for non exising value in Publications PMID will be NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can use `left join` for instance:

```
SELECT v.PMID
FROM STRING_SPLIT('29535196,29533737,29425496,28495678,26688618' ,',') v LEFT JOIN
     Publications p
     ON v.value = p.PMID
WHERE p.PMID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Having a little bit of trouble getting v(pmid) to work if I change it to   as v LEFT JOIN
  and the select to select "Value" then it works.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1314159 . . . That is really weird.  It doesn't accept a table alias with a column name (see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4a659d76a106f00662b2f41659cdfa3).  I think that is a parsing bug.